# Using LiveCharts with WPF, how to set the Columns starting positions on YAxes around a negative number?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, livecharts

Currently I have something like this. Where the starting Column position on YAxes is 0.

[image: Chart That I made]

**Window4.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CartesianChartGraph.Window4"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CartesianChartGraph"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window4" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Window4ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart  LegendLocation="None" DisableAnimations="True">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
                <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Values="{Binding Bar1Values}" StrokeThickness="2" 
                                 Stroke="YellowGreen" Fill="Blue" StackMode="Values" DataLabels="false" />
                <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Values="{Binding Bar2Values}" StrokeThickness="2" 
                                Stroke="YellowGreen" Fill="Transparent" StackMode="Values" DataLabels="false"  />
                <lvc:StackedColumnSeries />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Browser"  
                          Labels="{Binding Labels}" 
                          Separator="{x:Static lvc:DefaultAxes.CleanSeparator}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Name="Axis" Title="Usage" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" MinValue="-90" >
                    <lvc:Axis.Sections>
                        <lvc:AxisSection Value="{Binding YAxis}" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Red"/>
                    </lvc:Axis.Sections>
                </lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
                <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="OnlySender" ShowSeries="False"/>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window4ViewModel.cs**

```
using LiveCharts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CartesianChartGraph
{
    public class Window4ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public double YAxis { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> Bar1Values { get; set; }
        public ChartValues<double> Bar2Values { get; set; }        
        public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
        public List<string> Labels { get; set; }
        public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

        public Window4ViewModel() 
        {
            Bar1Values = new ChartValues<double> {-40, -50, -78, -80 };
            Bar2Values = new ChartValues<double> { -20, -80, -10, -50 };            
            Labels = new List<string> { "Chrome", "Mozilla", "Opera", "IE" };
            Formatter = value => value + " dBm";
            YAxis = 20;
            
        }
    }
}
```

And need something more like this. Where I want the starting Column position on YAxes at -90.
[image: How I want the Chart to look]

Tried to look through the LiveCharts documentation and code and couldn't figure it out.
Appreciate the Help